# Laravel DB first() "Trying to get property of non-object"

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I run a query using Laravel's DB `first()` which returns an object, when I check using `dd()` or `vardump()`. But when I try to print the value using `echo ($promotion->pp_name);` it gives error, but same property shows while `dd($promotion->pp_name);`

`<?php dd($promotion->pp_name); ?>` prints *"urgent"*

`<?php echo ($promotion->pp_name); ?>` but it gives *"Trying to get property of non-object"*

Full object dump results: `<?php dd($promotion); ?>`

```
    {#196 ▼
  +"ppo_id": 23
  +"ppo_prj_id": 68
  +"ppo_pp_id": 4
  +"ppo_updated_date": "2014-05-20"
  +"ppo_status": 1
  +"pp_id": 4
  +"pp_name": "urgent"
  +"pp_dispText": "I want my project to be marked as an urgent project"
  +"pp_amount": "5.00"
  +"pp_updated_date": "2013-08-09"
  +"pp_status": 1
}
```

and the function that return this object.

```
function getProjectPromotion($value='')
{
    $project_id = $value; 

    $promotion =     DB::table('project_promotion_option')
                    ->join('project_promotion', 'project_promotion_option.ppo_pp_id', '=', 'project_promotion.pp_id')
                    ->where('ppo_prj_id',  '=' ,  $project_id )
                    ->first(); 

    return $promotion; 

}
```

Comment: Can you post your code for this query also your code that dumps this object?

Comment: Hi @IvankaTodorova i updated the function that return result and dump of this object yo can see at bottom.

Comment: Where do you execute the code after the function?

Comment: function is in helper.php dump is in view. 
function is working fine as it get data and returned object. problem is to echo it. echo ($promotion->pp_name);

Comment: How do you pass it to the view?

Comment: sorry i updated comments pls check

Comment: Yes, but how do you pass `$promotion` to the view where you try to `echo` the properties of this object?

Comment: helper.php is autoloaded so function can access anywhere in my view i call function this like this. <?php $promotion =  getProjectPromotion( 1 );  ?>

  <?php dd ($promotion);  ?>

Comment: Okay, do you call the function and the echo in the same view?

Comment: yes same view. even this is working.  dd ($promotion->pp_name);

Comment: what is difference vs "dd ($promotion->pp_name);" and  "echo ($promotion->pp_name)"; with dd its working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you calling this method in a loop? When you do a dd(), the script stops with the right result after the first loop run and all is good. But when you do echo in a loop, it continues and my guess is that at some point you pass some corrupted data that breaks the method.

We would need to see the code excerpt where you are calling the mentioned method to verify this hunch.

Comment: Yes  i call this function in for-each loop where it get prj->id from each iterations Thanks for suggesting this i think query return null when promotion not found in some iteration. let me dig-down further

Answer (score 1):

As Tadas Paplauskas suggest because the function call the query run in foreach each loop and in some iteration DB::first() method return null so echo gets error. i solved this by checking first if the value is set.

```
 <?php  if (isset($promotion->pp_name)) {
           echo $promotion->pp_name;
   }  ?>
```